# Catch Exception in Cakephp 3 : not working

Tags: php, cakephp, exception, cakephp-3.0

I try to catch exceptions in Cakephp v3.0, but it doesn't seems to work :

```
    try{
    $email = new Email('default');
    $email->from([Configure::read('email') => Configure::read('emailName')])
        ->to(Configure::read('email'))
        ->bcc($to)
        ->subject(__('XXXX') . ' : ' . __('XXXX'))
        ->template('fail', 'default')
        ->emailFormat('html')
        ->send();
} catch (Exception $ex) {
}
```

It doesn't catch the exception :

```
Could not send email: mail(): Failed to connect to mailserver at "localhost" port 25, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use ini_set() Cake\Network\Exception\SocketException
```

Pretty annoying, I'm using it to catch fail email send on a local server.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You're pointing to either an imported class, or to one in the same namespace as the current class, so check what `Exception` in your code actually refers to - if I were to guess, I'd say that it's probably not to the native `\Exception` class in the global namespace. ps, please always include stacktraces and context information when posting errors!

Comment: Using RuntimeException instead of Exception, did the trick.
Thanks !

Comment: @Gael.D I have been suffering with the problem. use your solution. couldn't any output.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Adding the answer here, just to bring dow the unanswered questions stats down:

You need to use `\Exception` or a more specific, namespaced, exception name

```
try {
    // code
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    // error
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't have thought of that in 100 years.

Comment: @JoeC JoseLorenzo is the founder/owner of cakephp

Comment: There's no CakePHP magic to this answer, it's basic PHP namespacing.

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar issue when I tried to catch `MissingConnectionException`.

In my case, following lines solved my problem.

```
use Cake\Core\Exception\Exception;
...
try {
    // Your test code here
} catch (Exception $e) {
    ...
}
```

Hope it would be help for you.

Answer (score 2):

You could try using `try` - `catch`

```
try {
   $email = new Email('default');
   $email->from([Configure::read('email') => Configure::read('emailName')])
    ->to(Configure::read('email'))
    ->bcc($to)
    ->subject(__('XXXX') . ' : ' . __('XXXX'))
    ->template('fail', 'default')
    ->emailFormat('html')
    ->send();
} catch (\PDOException $e) {
    $error = $e->getMessage();
}
```