# CakePHP ignore Record not found in table exception

Tags: php, exception, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

There is no record with ID 0 on purpos. And I'm doing

```
$id = 0;
try { 
  $object = $this->MyModel->get($id); 
} catch(Exception $e){
  //Nothing
}
```

And I still get the exception thrown "Record not found in table".

**How can I ignore, that there is no record with the given ID with `get($id)` and avoid the exception?**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Catch Exception in Cakephp 3 : not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32569444/catch-exception-in-cakephp-3-not-working)

Comment: Furthermore, the specific exception here is `\Cake\Datasource\Exception\RecordNotFoundException`.

Comment: @ndm I tried also to catch that exact exception, but it didn't work.

Comment: Did you read @Szymon's link? It's exactly this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$this->MyModel->find('all', ['conditions' => ['id' => $id]])->first();` seems to be the shortest code without getting an error on non-existence of an element.

The other problem was, that I used `Exception` instead of the correct `\Exception`, that's why the error was thrown despite the try-catch-block.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try making the relationship a `LEFT` join.

```
Insde MyModelTable.php

        $this->MyModel->belongsTo('ParentTable', [
            'foreignKey' => 'parent_id',
            'joinType' => 'LEFT',
        ]);
```

Answer (score -1):

Why not using if statement?

```
$id = 0;
$object = [];
if ($id){
  $object = $this->MyModel->get($id); 
} else{
  $object = [];
}
```

Comment: No, that doesn't guarantee that another id=1231243233 doesn't exist. I don't want an error at all.